# What correspondences of Grahas to different Mahavidyas are correct?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, dasha-mahavidya

Correspondences common on the Internet come from some unknown source. And Sanjay Rath for some reason repeats it in his books and magazine.

However, Kokilarnava Tantra 25:54-282 contains significantly different correspondences:

▪︎ Kalika — Surya (Sun).

▪︎ Chhinnamasta — Rahu (North Node).

▪︎ Tara — Chandra (Moon).

▪︎ Dhumavati — Shani (Saturn).

▪︎ Shrividya (Tripura Sundari) — Guru (Jupiter).

▪︎ Bagala — Bhauma (Mars).

▪︎ Bhuvaneshvari — Bhrigu (Venus).

▪︎ Matangi — Budha (Mercury).

▪︎ Bhairavi — Ketu (South Node).

▪︎ Kamala — Kulamarthanda (Lagna?).

Comment: Any online source for Kokilarnava Tantra? Or you have a hard copy?

Comment: I don't have a link to a pdf copy. In google-search, it gives out only a pdf with a partial translation of this Tantra into Russian, - the publication is called: "Kaula tantra sangraha. Anthology of texts of Hindu Tantra".

Comment: Every tantra gives a different correspondance to graha. But, none is wrong, as every tantra is Sthala Vishesha. And under such cause, 64 tantras are assigned to each Kranta. Thus, with Sthala the effect of Mahavidyas may change over Grahas. As Jyotish realted things are very very specific about place.

Comment: If in any other Tantras there are correspondences between Devatas and Grahas, then publish it. So far, Kokilarnava is the only Tantra.

Answer (score 2):

I add a more detailed translation of fragments of Kokilarnava Tantra:

"*In Eastern Amnaya*:
Mahavidya - Kalika,
Siddhavidya - Vani,
Vidya - Kulluki,
Upavidya - Kurukulla,
Shiva - Mahakala,
Bhairava - Kalabhairava,
Ganesha - Vakrathunda,
Kshetrapala - Antaka,
Devi - Mahasiddheshvari,
Yogini - Charavigraha,
**Graha - Surya**"

"*In Hadi*:
Mahavidya - Chhinnamasta,
Siddhavidya - Vajreshvari,
Vidya - Kalaratri,
Upavidya - Aghoramukhi,
Shiva - Karala,
Bhairava - Krodha,
Ganesha - Gajanana,
Kshetrapala - Mahadeva,
Yogini - Kaulini,
**Graha - Rahu**"

"*In South Amnaya*:
Mahavidya - Tarini,
Siddhavidya - Gauri,
Vidya - Mangala,
Upavidya - Malini,
Shiva - Akshobhya,
Bhairava - Vatuka,
Ganesha - Ganadhyaksha,
Kshetrapala - Arthavaha,
Yogini - Aghora,
**Graha - Chandra**"

"*In Hadi*:
Mahavidya - Dhumavati,
Siddhavidya - Jvalamukhi,
Vidya - Bheda,
Upavidya - Tvarita,
Shiva - Aghora,
Bhairava - Unmatta,
Ganesha - Ekadanta, Kshetrapala - Damara,
Yogini - Ratnamala,
**Graha - Shani**"

"*In Western Amnaya*:
Mahavidya - Shrividya,
Siddhavidya - Bhavani,
Vidya - Vidyarajni,
Upavidya - Brahmapara,
Shiva - Rajarajeshvara,
Bhairava - Asitanga,
Ganesha - Haridragananayaka,
Kshetrapala - Indramurti,
Yogini - Sundari,
**Graha - Guru**"

"*In Hadi*:
Mahavidya - Bagala,
Siddhavidya - Pratyangira,
Vidya - Prabhakara,
Upavidya - Vagvadini,
Shiva - Tryambakeshvara,
Bhairava - Bhishana,
Ganesha - Vighnaraja,
Kshetrapala - Ripusudana,
Yogini - Ambika,
**Graha - Bhauma**"

"*In Northern Amnaya*:
Mahavidya - Bhuvaneshwari,
Siddhavidya - Annapurna,
Vidya - Parameshvari,
Upavidya - Varuni,
Shiva - Parameshvara,
Bhairava - Ruru,
Ganesha - Ganapati,
Kshetrapala - Ulka,
Yogini - Madana,
**Graha - Bhrigu**"

"*In Hadi*:
Mahavidya - Matangi,
Siddhavidya - Vashini,
Vidya - Sharik,
Upavidya - Kubjika,
Shiva - Mahesha,
Bhairava - Chanda,
Ganesha - Vinayaka,
Kshetrapala - Raktapani,
Yoginis - Ekavaktra and Ashtavaktra,
**Graha - Budha**"

"*In Upper Amnaya*:
Mahavidya - Bhairavi, Siddhavidya - Durga,
Vidya - Kiratini,
Upavidya - Ashvarudha,
Shiva - Kukkuteshvara, Bhairava - Samhara,
Ganesha - Uchchishta, Kshetrapala - Ushmada,
Yogini - Raudri,
**Graha - Ketu**"

"*In Hadi*:
Mahavidya - Kamala,
Siddhavidya - Kamakhya,
Vidya - Kameshvari,
Upavidya - Kamakala,
Shiva - Narayana,
Bhairava - Kapali,
Ganesha - Kshipraprasada,
Kshetrapala - Kamalakhyavibhu,
Yogini - Vyapini,
**Graha - Kulamarthanda**"